# can my children play multiplayer?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My 4 children have their own accounts and want to play together in multiplayer. 3 children have Samsung tablets, but the fourth has a Windows 10 computer. How should we set up multiplayer?

(we have minecraft bedrock if that's needed) Please explain your answers in detail.

Comment: bedrock edition

Comment: You’ve got bedrock edition on all four devices, yes? Including the PC.

Comment: yes we do have bedrock on all 4  devices

Answer (score 3):

If you have Bedrock on each device, you should be able to natively cross-play between all of them, no need for external software.

At most, you may need to or want to look into setting up a bedrock server to host on LAN, but that’s not even necessary if the one with the computer will be able to host it every time. In Minecraft’s [help section](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360035131391-How-to-Play-Minecraft-Multiplayer#h_01F6QGXYJ4FMGEN8TBPF3TRQ24) for LAN on W10 it should be as simple as someone doing the following steps (after making sure everyone is on the same wifi network:

**Start a LAN game**

- Click Play.
- Click the pen icon to create a new world or edit a current world.
- Go to Multiplayer and make sure that Visible to LAN Players is enabled.
- Choose Create or Play to start the world.

**Join a LAN game**

- Go to the Play menu.
- Click the Friends tab and look for available LAN Games.

You should also be able to  [set up a dedicated bedrock server](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360035131651-Dedicated-Servers-for-Minecraft-on-Bedrock-) but that’s a little more complicated. The advantage though is that it doesn’t require the same player to host each time, as it’s a separate instance that anyone can join. And it should natively work on LAN, though finding and connecting is a *little* more complex as you’ll need to figure out your **local** IP (you don’t need your global IP unless you’re trying to make it connectable to devices not on your home network).

Comment: lan stands for something something network?

Comment: @Ashfur07 Local Area Network.  Basically, not connecting to the greater internet.  A simple method is having all the devices connected to the same WiFi router, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible with [Floodgate](https://github.com/GeyserMC/Floodgate/wiki) and [Geyser](https://github.com/GeyserMC/Geyser).

> Geyser is a bridge between Minecraft Bedrock Edition and Minecraft Java Edition, closing the gap for those wanting to play true cross-platform.

> Floodgate is a hybrid mode plugin which allows for Minecraft Bedrock accounts to join Minecraft Java Edition servers without needing a Minecraft Java Edition account. This plugin can be installed in addition to Geyser, but, unlike Geyser, Floodgate can only be installed as a plugin on Spigot (including Paper and forks), Bungeecord, and Velocity, and can only be utilized on servers that have it installed.

Geyser is the program that lets you connect Minecraft Bedrock Edition to Minecraft Java server and Floodgate is a plugin that you install onto the Minecraft server to let you use accounts from the Bedrock editions of Minecraft (Android Minecraft versions are Bedrock editions and Minecraft versions on PC are Java editions).

If you have bought Minecraft on all 3 tablets, and on the Windows 10 PC, you are ready to set up everything. Just follow the video guides of Geyser and the text instructions of Floodgate.

Keep in mind that you need to set up everything on a powerful PC. A Windows 10 PC should do the trick, assuming it has more than 4GB of RAM. You need to host a server on a PC, and then that PC and all the tablets need to connect to the server.

Once you have everything ready, the server will appear on the tab "Friends" on the Bedrock editions and on the PC you will need to connect to "localhost".

Useful links:

- [These](https://paper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server/index.html) are the text instructions to install and setup a Minecraft Java Edition Server. It is a "Paper" server. This version works great with Floodgate.
- [These](https://github.com/GeyserMC/Geyser/wiki/Setup#standalone-setup) are the text instructions to install a standalone version of Geyser.
- [These](https://github.com/GeyserMC/Geyser/wiki/Floodgate#standalone-setup-geyser-and-floodgate-are-not-on-the-same-server) are the text instructions to install Floodgate on a server.

Comment: Hold on; the question mentions Bedrock, and doesn’t talk about Java edition. Even if everything you’ve said here is the way to cross-play between Java and Bedrock, the OP should be able to simply use Bedrock on all devices. Bedrock is available on PC, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily join a LAN game if you are on the same internet. Click "friends" and click the open world. One must start the world, and do nothing after. I recomend the PC because it will be least laggy.

If you aren't, then you can create a server. Take an old PC, it doesn't need Minecraft. Download here: https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server/bedrock
Search on google how to update the server when a new update comes. It is too long to explain here.

Comment: They could run the server on the same PC that the client is running on, unless it's a particularly anemic computer. No need for an additional PC either way